# Create react app, yarn workspaces dependency issue

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, yarn-workspaces

I'm building a multi-module project with create-react-app, typescript and yarn workspaces.

the structure is:

```
package.json
packages
  - create-react-app-project
  - other-lib-project
    - tsconfig.json
    - package.json
    - src/
    - dist/
```

the lib project builds fine, but when I run it I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'random' of undefined
```

Where random is a property of faker. In the compiled output the import statement for faker shows up as:

```
var faker_1 = require("faker");
```

I thought that when webpack compiled the create react app project it would bundle the dependencies of my library, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

how should I bundle my library so its dependencies are available at runtime in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've gone with is to add the library project to the paths in my main projects tsconfig.json. eg.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@my-namespace/main-project": ["./src"],
      "@my-namespace/lib-project": ["../lib-project"]
    }
}
```

This uses the compiled lib assets from the build folder but still bundles the required modules in the main build/